# AWS API Gateway request validation - supported types and formats

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have been experimenting with AWS API Gateway and request validation according to OpenAPI Specification (see [https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#:~:text=OpenAPI%20defines%20the%20following%20built,07%2D21T17%3A32%3A28Z](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#:%7E:text=OpenAPI%20defines%20the%20following%20built,07%2D21T17%3A32%3A28Z))

It seems that AWS does not conform to specification, at least for `date` format. When I try model with

```json
{
  "date": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "date-time"
  }
}
```

then it seems that API Gateway does not validate content at all (any arbitrary string is allowed).

On the other way `date-time` works properly as defined in OpenAPI and RFC-3339.

Is there any official documentation or compatibility matrix? I wasn't able to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS API Gateway does support date-time format validation. Just make sure to [enable request validation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-validation-set-up.html) (disabled by default)

I've tested request with date-time string property in the body:

- **validation disabled:** no error when any arbitrary string is passed
- **validation enabled:** an error with status 400 is returned with body `{"message": "Invalid request body"}`, there's a message in the api gateway log that says that request body does not match model schema (log also contains details about the value and requested format).